# Stacking with missing predictions from models

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model

There are several models A, B, ..., Z. These models may not give a prediction for any of entities from id1, id2, id3, .., idn.

What approaches will be more suitable for stacking in these situations?

For example,

- model A can not predict for id1, but can predict for id2, ..., idn;
- model B can not predict for id2, but can predict for id1, id3, ...,
  idn;
- model C can not predict for id2 and id3, but can predict for id1, ..., id4, ..., idn.